# NMaximize stops evaluating my function when run in parallel

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parallelization

I am trying to maximize the results of a Monte Carlo simulation with respect to some input variables.

```
ClearAll["Global'*"];
gratInit = 100.; rate7520 = 0.022; rateFree = 0.03;
currentstock = 100.; dividendRate = 0.018; 
dividendMult = 1. + dividendRate;
AnnuityPayment = 1/2 (gratInit rate7520) (1/((rate7520 + 1)^yr - 1) + 1);
yr = 2; mu = 0.07; sigma = 0.15; iter = 10000;

returns[years_, mean_, sd_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mean, sd], years];
rwalks = Table[returns[yr, mu, sigma], {iter}];
d1[K_, T_] := (Log[currentstock/K] + T (-dividendRate + rateFree + sigma^2/2))/(sigma Sqrt[T]);
Call[str_, T_] := 1/E^(dividendRate T) currentstock CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], d1[str, T]];


spot[k_] := FoldList[#1 (#2 + 1) &, currentstock, rwalks[[k]]]
Spot = Table[spot[i], {i, iter}];


zRisk[T_, r_] := Quantile[LogNormalDistribution[mu T, sigma Sqrt[T]], r];
StrikeRisk[T_, r_] := currentstock zRisk[T, r];
MCRiskRunIter = Function[{D1, D2, r1, r2, n}, 
 dollarsRisk = {D1, D2}; 
 risk = {r1, r2};
 strikePricesRisk = Table[StrikeRisk[i, risk[[i]]], {i, yr}]; 
 priceOfCallsRisk = Table[Call[strikePricesRisk[[i]], i], {i, yr}]; 
 numbOfContractsRisk = Table[dollarsRisk[[i]]/priceOfCallsRisk[[i]], {i, yr}]; 
 MrktRisk = gratInit - Total[dollarsRisk]; 
 For[j = 1, j <= yr, j++, 
  If[Spot[[n]][[j + 1]] >= strikePricesRisk[[j]], 
   MrktRisk = -AnnuityPayment + MrktRisk (dividendMult + rwalks[[n]][[j]]) + 
    numbOfContractsRisk[[j]] Spot[[n]][[j + 1]];, 
   MrktRisk = MrktRisk*(dividendMult + rwalks[[n]][[j]]) - AnnuityPayment;]; 
  If[MrktRisk <= 0, MrktRisk = 0; Break[]];]; MrktRisk];


MCRiskRun[D1_?NumericQ, D2_?NumericQ, r1_?NumericQ, r2_?NumericQ] := 
 (output = Mean[ParallelTable[MCRiskRunIter[D1, D2, r1, r2, n], {n, 1, iter}]]; 
  Print[output]; output)


WP = 6;
PG = 2;
MaxIter = 10;

OptimalResults = NMaximize[{MCRiskRun[D1, D2, r1, r2], {D1 >= 0, D2 >= 0, 
  D1 + D2 <= gratInit, 0 <= r1 <= 1, 0 <= r2 <= 1}}, {D1, D2, r1, r2}, MaxIterations -> MaxIter, WorkingPrecision -> WP, PrecisionGoal -> PG]
```

When I run with one processor, everything goes great. When I try to use `ParallelTable` in my function (as above), `NMinimize` evaluates my function for a while, but then stops getting number values for my function. Below is the point in the output file where the transition occurs:

> ```
> 68.4242      
> 69.5474   
> 68.1978   
> 69.5474   
> Mean[Join[HoldComplete[{45.6694, 60.7975, 92.762, 44.9912, 75.1937, 75.7598, etc.
> ```

If I limit the Monte Carlo to 500 or so iterations, it still works fine. But I would like the Monte Carlo to go through 10k iterations or so. Is this a memory issue? Am I doing something wrong? I can provide full code if desired.

Comment: Having the definitions for all functions and parameters would make it easier to help.

Comment: I added the whole program. I would like to run with iters=10000 and MaxIters=500 or so.

Comment: Can you further whittle down your problem? The code looks a bit unwieldy...

Comment: I understand, and will try to do so tomorrow when I have more time. I guess my main question was why would NMaximize evaluate my MCRiskRun function for a while and then just decide to stop doing it. Seems odd, unless it ran out of memory, but it is not saying that. I will try to post more condensed code soon.